# Const variables and instances storing

Tags: flutter, dart

I just have read about "const" widget allocation in build method, so in this scenario, widgets get allocated when the app starts, how they stores and where?. Do they increase apps size?

Answer (score 1):

**How compiled Flutter widgets are stored and where?**

Flutter application is AOT-compiled (ahead-of-time) to native platform code. Each Flutter widget is compiled to native widgets and they are rendered to [Skia](https://skia.org/dev/flutter) canvas which is shown to the end user platform. Platform sends back all events which are than handled by compiled Flutter code.

I do highly recommend to check those articles:

- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/The-Engine-architecture
- https://medium.com/47billion/flutter-how-does-it-works-6e4c73842e67

**When to use `const` widgets in Flutter?**

Use `const` widgets where possible in `StatefullWidget`

Why? Simply remember that calling `StatefullWidget` `setState` will rebuild the whole widget. By specifying `const` for the child widgets of `StatefullWidget` you'll say that they do not need to be rebuilt on `setState` call.

Here is the link to official documentation:

- https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html#performance-considerations

Comment: Thank you @Hanna, if I make `const` for example function that returns widget, will it be rebuilt when build method is called

Comment: @dagdk, getters, setters and methods can't be declared as `const`. Use it for widgets and variables to boost app performance. For example if you declare `const Text('text')` twice in your app the memory for it on compilation will be allocated only once and it will be never changed on state change. 
If you have hundreds of calls `const Text('text')` it will improve performance a lot: 
  1) allocated once, takes less memory, makes your app faster
  2) will not be ever updated, always the same as compiled.

**Conclusion**: what you declare with `const` is built one time and is never changed

Answer (score 0):

Regarding whether they increase app size:

I believe Dart 2.0 made `const` optional, that is, the compiler will mark it as `const` on its own given the right context. Here are a few resources that point to this:

["Don't use const redundantly"](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#dont-use-const-redundantly) - Effective Dart Usage

["Dart 2 introduces optional new and const" - Announcing Dart 2.0](https://medium.com/dartlang/announcing-dart-2-80ba01f43b6)

So, if the compiler does this automatically, I think it's safe to assume that there won't be a compromise on app/size performance. I hope this answers your question.